# Форма обратной связи с валидацией и активацией кнопки "Скачать"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, валидация

Все доброго времени суток. Есть такая форма (представлена на картинке №1). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда клиент вводил свой **E-mail**, *Во-первых* происходила проверка правильности написания почты, а *Во-вторых*, после того как клиент нажимает на кнопку **"Отправить"**(понятное дело, что почта должна быть введена), вместо этой кнопки появлялась кнопка **"Скачать"** и клиент уже нажимая на нее мог скачать файл, которых лежит в корне папки сайта.
Я сделал пока просто верстку, где клиент может ввести все что угодно(или вообще ничего) и нажать на кнопку, чтобы скачать файл и всё.

Подскажите как можно это сделать проще, можно хоть *PHP*, *хоть JS, желательно чистый или небольшую библиотеку использовать*. Заранее большое спасибо, а то уже кучу времени на это потратил.

То есть, нужно:

1. Валидация одного поля E-mail
2. После нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" при верном введённом E-mail появлялась вместо той кнопки, кнопка "Скачать".

**Форма, которая сейчас на сайте**↓↓↓

[image: Форма, которая сейчас на сайте]

**Форма, которая нужна(в макете)↓↓↓**

[image: Форма, которая нужна(в макете)]
[image: Форма, которая нужна(в макете)]

**Мой код данной формы. Она активируется как модальное окно, при нажатии на кнопку появляется данная форма↓↓↓**

```js
!(function(e) {
  'function' != typeof e.matches &&
    (e.matches =
      e.msMatchesSelector ||
      e.mozMatchesSelector ||
      e.webkitMatchesSelector ||
      function(e) {
        for (
          var t = this,
            o = (t.document || t.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(e),
            n = 0; o[n] && o[n] !== t;

        )
          ++n
        return Boolean(o[n])
      }),
    'function' != typeof e.closest &&
    (e.closest = function(e) {
      for (var t = this; t && 1 === t.nodeType;) {
        if (t.matches(e)) return t
        t = t.parentNode
      }
      return null
    })
})(window.Element.prototype)

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* Записываем в переменные массив элементов-кнопок и подложку.
      Подложке зададим id, чтобы не влиять на другие элементы с классом overlay*/
  var modalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-open-modal'),
    overlay = document.querySelector('.js-overlay-modal'),
    closeButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-modal-close')

  /* Перебираем массив кнопок */
  modalButtons.forEach(function(item) {
    /* Назначаем каждой кнопке обработчик клика */
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      /* Предотвращаем стандартное действие элемента. Так как кнопку разные
            люди могут сделать по-разному. Кто-то сделает ссылку, кто-то кнопку.
            Нужно подстраховаться. */
      e.preventDefault()

      /* При каждом клике на кнопку мы будем забирать содержимое атрибута data-modal
            и будем искать модальное окно с таким же атрибутом. */
      var modalId = this.getAttribute('data-modal'),
        modalElem = document.querySelector(
          '.modal[data-modal="' + modalId + '"]'
        )

      /* После того как нашли нужное модальное окно, добавим классы
            подложке и окну чтобы показать их. */
      modalElem.classList.add('active')
      overlay.classList.add('active')
    }) // end click
  }) // end foreach

  closeButtons.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      var parentModal = this.closest('.modal')

      parentModal.classList.remove('active')
      overlay.classList.remove('active')
    })
  }) // end foreach

  document.body.addEventListener(
    'keyup',
    function(e) {
      var key = e.keyCode

      if (key == 27) {
        document.querySelector('.modal.active').classList.remove('active')
        document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.remove('active')
      }
    },
    false
  )

  overlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.modal.active').classList.remove('active')
    this.classList.remove('active')
  })
}) // end ready
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #494049;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

a,
ul,
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.btn {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #226ce6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  /* identical to box height */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.btn_checkbox {
  min-width: 314px;
  height: 65px;
  background-color: #226ce6;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  gap: 10px;
}


/* Стили для подложки */

.overlay {
  /* Скрываем подложку  */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(70, 70, 72, 0.5);
  z-index: 20;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}


/* Стили для модальных окон */

.modal {
  /* Скрываем окна  */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*  Установаем ширину окна  */
  max-width: 502px;
  max-height: 450px;
  /*  Центрируем и задаем z-index */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* z-index: 30;  */
  /* Должен быть выше чем у подложки  */
  /* position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; */
  z-index: 30;
  /*  Побочные стили   */
  /* box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff; */
  transition: 0.3s all;
}


/* Стили для активных классов подложки и окна */

.modal.active,
.overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.modal_window {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  max-width: 502px;
  max-height: 450px;
  padding: 60px 94px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 35px;
}

.modal_title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 143%;
  max-width: 314px;
}

.model_form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 35px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.email_input {
  width: 314px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #f2f6fa;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 8px rgba(199, 196, 196, 0.25);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 160%;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.email_input:active,
.email_input:focus {
  outline-color: #226ce6;
}

.btn_and_checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.input_btn {
  border: none;
  display: none;
}

.check {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.check>input:focus,
.check>input:active {
  outline-color: #226ce6;
}
```

```html
<!-- Модальных окон -->

<div class="modal" data-modal="1">
  <div class="modal_window">
    <div class="modal_title">
      Для получения ссылки на скачивание введите адрес своей электронной почты
    </div>
    <form action="#" class="model_form">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" class="email_input" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" required />
      <div class="btn_and_checkbox">
        <a class="btn_checkbox" href="./file.zip" download="">Скачать<img src="./img/fi-rs-download.svg" width="24" alt=""
                        /></a>
        <!-- <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn input_btn" /> -->

        <div class="check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" checked="checked" />
          <span>Соглашаюсь с условиями передачи данных</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Подложка под модальным окном -->
<div class="overlay js-overlay-modal"></div>

<!-- Конец модального окна -->

<!-- Кнопка открытия модального окна -->
<div class="btn down_btn">
  <a href="#" class="js-open-modal btn" data-modal="1">
                                Скачать <img src="./img/fi-rs-download.svg" alt=""
                            /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: как вы себе представляете процесс валидации? что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Здравствуйте, простую проверку, написал человек email, а никакие нибудь цифры с буквами. Существует такая почта или нет, не важно, главное чтобы правильно было написано, через собаку